# Mixed authentication on an intranet site using ntlm with the posibillity to change the logged in user

Tags: asp.net-core, ntlm, intranet

iam building an intranet site with asp.net core and want the user to be logged in automatically with their windows accounts. This works perfectly when Windows Authentication is turned on.
My problem is, that we have several pc's where a generic domain user is logged in and the employees want to see their information on the intranet site. Therefor it is required that the user can login with their own active directory user in the intranet site.

Employee opens intranet site -> the generic user gets logged in and no information is shown -> now user clicks on logout and can then re-login with their own ad-user and password -> now the site shows their information.

I searched around the web, but iam not very fit with all this NTLM, Kerberos,... stuff.
Is my scenario even possible with my configuration?

Thank you in advance for the help

Best Regards 
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Set your initial login page to Windows Int Auth.  If they get success, give them a cookie and get them to their content. If they fail, pass them to a page with anon access enabled. Put a form on that page to collect the username and password and test it.  If the password works, give them a cookie.
Make sure you use SSL/TLS as you are passing a plain text password.